# Check for a data range in new data view in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need to update my dataGridView(FilterGrid) according to user needs. So I need to filter my data in few conditions.
[image]

I created new data view and assigned that data view to my grid view. It works fine with report category and product

```
If ProductCombo.Text = "Shoe" Then
            Dim dv As DataView
            dv = New DataView(SilexDatabaseDataSet.Tables("Sales"), "ShoeID LIKE 'SH*'", "ShoeID Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            FilterGrid.DataSource = dv
        End If
```

But I need to filter my data by the date also. I get the date from datetime picker. When I create dataView, I need to add the date range. But it doesnot work.

```
If ProductCombo.Text = "Shoe" And DateReportCheck.Checked = True Then
            Dim dv As DataView
            dv = New DataView(SilexDatabaseDataSet.Tables("Sales"), "ShoeID LIKE 'SH*' AND (Date BETWEEN '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' AND '" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "')", "ShoeID Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            FilterGrid.DataSource = dv
        End If
```

Please HELP.

Comment: What `DateTimePicker1.Value` provides is a datetime value. You are interested in a specific string representation of that value (i.e., where you bring the format you wish into account). The only reason why your code even compiles is because you haven't written `Option Strict On` on the top of your file (what is not-recommendable at all unless perfectly knowing what you are doing). An example of acceptable format would be: `DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`. After some research + tests, you will quickly solve it. BTW you can use `RowFilter` rather than redefining the `DataSource`.

Comment: Thanks @varocarbas . Now I'm using `dv = New DataView(SilexDatabaseDataSet.Tables("Sales"), "ShoeID LIKE 'SH*' AND (Date >= '" & Date.ParseExact(DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) & "' AND Date <='" & Date.ParseExact(DateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) & "')", "ShoeID Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)`

Comment: But Still It does not return the proper output.

Comment: You didn't understand what I said and your correction is delivering EXACTLY what the previous version was doing. I insist: write `Strict Option On` on top of your files (and this new code of yours wouldn't compile either). You have to convert a datetime into string;  with datetime.ToString(format), you do that; but if then you take this string and use Date.ParseExact you are reconverting it into Date again!! Why are you doing such a thing! Please, try to understand what you write before writing it!

Comment: PS: your original question was almost offtopic (i.e., numerous problems deriving from basic understanding lacks, not likely to be helpful to anyone else; because someone with basic understanding of the date/time type in .NET wouldn't ever do such a thing); your behaviour after my first comment has converted it into completely off-topic. You didn't want to understand the ideas, just wrote something without even understanding what you were doing. This is not what SO is about; and it is not helpful for your learning either (why writing code without understanding it?). My help ends here.